# is there possible to create ylim just show number following the data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I want to make some plot of my data, i.e on epoch 1 I got prediction 0.67 then ylim show the starting value was 0.67, not the other number and when I want to show the highest number on my data i.e 0.89 then ylim show the highest number, I'm wondering is that possible to create ylim starting point value on my data and highest value in my data?

here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure(dpi=128, figsize=(10,6))
for fname in ('/content/drive/My Drive/data/models/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.0001_50_256_yes/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.0001_50_256_yes_history.bin','/content/drive/My Drive/data/models/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.001_25_256_no/unet_mobilenet_jt_0.001_25_256_no_history.bin'):
    data=pd.read_pickle(fname)
 
    plt.plot(data['precision'])
    plt.plot(data['val_precision'])
    plt.title('pretrained and not pretrained precision')
    plt.ylabel('precision')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train pre-trained', 'validation pre-trained','train not pre-trained', 'validation not pre trained'], loc='lower right')
plt.gcf()
plt.ylim = (min(ydata), max(ydata))
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([0,50])
axes.set_ylim([0.1,1])
```

so far, here is my plot I've made:
[image]

I've found some examples plot, and what I mean is want to make like this:

[image]

Comment: Just not calling `set_ylim()` would let maplotlib choose the limits.  You can set `axes.margins(y=0.02)` to have a 2% margin (default is 5%).  Please don't do `plt.ylim = ...` because `plt.ylim` is a function which you are erasing.

Comment: @JohanC thanks for correcting my code, I've tried to change `set_ylim()` to `axes.margins(y=0.02)` and it doesn't change anything like the Picture I give

Comment: @JohanC i thought my image showed up, sorry, I've edit my question

Comment: Oh, you want extra tick marks in the y-axis.  You could save all the `data[...][0]` into a list, and at the end call `axes.set_yticks(list_of_starts + [0, 1])`

Comment: @JohanC i see, its done, thanks for enlightening me